# SSD moved to new laptop but won't boot

Tags: boot, ssd, thinkpad

Bought a new [Thinkpad T510i-4314-9UG](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd003320) laptop, and took the old SSD 2.5" to the new laptop. Its BIOS settings are Quick boot disabled, drive type AHCI.

I can't get it to boot up, all i get is a typing line top left corner, and nothing more, cant write or anything. BIOS is set to boot from my SSD. Any advice?

Comment: Just plain standard, although i havent seen this kind of layout before. Im used to having the menues above, but here its listed downwards. Thinkpad T510i TYPE 4314-9UG - S/N R9-6HECE 10/08. Fast boot(Quick) is disabled, RSTe is AHCI.

Comment: Was the old machine originally installed with Windows 10, or something else? What was the make and model of the old laptop?

Comment: Look in bios for legacy boot support and disable secure boot. Probably trying to boot to UEFI mode.

Comment: Cant find legacy anywhere :S

Comment: Does this ever work? A drive with an installed OS is not the same as a 'Live' image. With installation the OS will make assumptions about its hardware that will be invalid on another computer. A live image will perform an initial query that an installed OS will not need to perform. I don't *know* here. Just guessing. Can anyone confirm?